# Prove that product of two matrices is $I$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

> The pair of variables $(x, y)$ are each functions of the pair of
>   variables $(u, v)$ and vice versa. Consider the matrices:
>   $$ A=\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}&  \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}} \\  \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} & \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}}\end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{ and }\quad
>  B=\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}&  \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} \\  \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}\end{matrix}\right)$$
>   Prove that $AB = I$, where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.

So, I multiplied these two matrices together, and I got 
$$AB = \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}
&   \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}
\\   \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}
&  \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}\end{matrix}\right). $$

Now I have to prove that $AB = \left(\begin{matrix}1 &0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$since $x = f(u, v)$ and $y = g(u, v)$, and $u,v$ are some functions of say $s$, by the multivariate chain rule we have: 
$$ \frac{dx}{ds} = \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{du}{ds} +\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{dv}{ds}.$$
I thought about substituting $x=s$ (can I do that...?), so that 
$$1=\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{du}{dx} +\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{dv}{dx},$$
and from here we get that the upper left element of $AB$ is $1$. Similarly, we could prove that the bottom right element is $1$.

But I have little clue as to how should I prove that 
$$\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} = 0, $$
for instance. Any help? (and while I don't ,,require'' a very rigorous solution, I'm already quite confused by multivariate calculus, so a solution without much handwaving would be appreciated! :) )

Comment: It is exactly the same. Namely, calculate $\frac{dx}{dy}$

Comment: I tried, so $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} $$, but how does one conclude that $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ and $y$ are independent variables

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0
$$

With this you can repeat the same argument to show the off-diagonal elements are zero

Comment: Again, I see that $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} $$, but there's $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in there, and not a partial derivative...? Can I just say that it's the same thing?

Comment: @VanDerWarden Well, why did you use the notation $dx/dy$ instead of $\partial x/\partial y$ to begin with? It is partial, because $x = x(u, v) = x(u(x,y), v(x,y))$, so x depends on more than one variable, hence the partial symbol.

Comment: I used $\frac{dx}{dy}$ because that's what I found on https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/

Comment: @VanDerWarden Chain rule also applies in multivariable calculus

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule is best stated as a formula for infinitesimals rather than either a total or partial derivative; you can work out the correct derivative later. We have $df=\partial_u f du+\partial_v f dv$ (where $\partial_a b$ is an abbreviation for $\frac{\partial_b}{\partial_a}$), so $\partial_x f=\partial_u f\partial_x u+\partial_v f\partial_x v$, which for $f$ equal to $x$ or $y$ gives what you need.

Comment: Ehmmm... How did you get from $df = \partial_ufdu+\partial_vfdv$ to $\partial_xf = \partial_uf\partial_xu+\partial_vf\partial_xv$? Because it's looks like you partially differentiated $du$, which is quite weird for me.

Comment: @VanDerWarden You divide out $dx$ rather than differentiating $du$, but *when* you perform this division you have to ask yourself what, if anything, is held constant when we take the limit to get a derivative. In this case we're holding $y$ constant, so we get $\partial_x f$ rather than $df/dx$, $\partial_x u$ instead of $du/dx$ etc.